# Django TypeError 'NoneType' when adding objects to ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to add an app to my Django project called "clinicaltrials" (CT) that stores data from the clinicaltrial.gov API.  Each trial may have multiple collaborators and multiple diseases, so I've set up additional models for them with a ManyToManyField. *(note: I originally tried to connect CT directly to my Company model, however not all possible companies are in my database so I'm capturing names as well in the CT model)*

The problem I'm running into is when I try to add the CT record to either of the additional models I get an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.  I would think that looking it up by `pk` as I'm doing would work.  This is my first time using a ManyToManyField and I've been wresting this for the past two days.  Where am I going wrong here?

**This is the function that I'm using to write to the models:**

```
def write_database(data):

    for trial in range(len(data)):

        # if the trial exists in the database continue to the next one
        if ClinicalTrial.objects.filter(nct_id=data[trial].get('nct_id')).exists():
            continue

        # create list of collaborators for later
        if data[trial].get('collaborators') is not None:
            collaborators = []
            collaborator_len = len(data[trial].get('collaborators'))
            for x in range(collaborator_len):
                collaborators.append(data[trial].get('collaborators')[x].get('name'))
        else:
            collaborators = None

        print(collaborators)

        # write trial info to database
        ct = ClinicalTrial()
        ct.nct_id = data[trial].get('nct_id')
        ct.status = data[trial].get('current_trial_status')
        ct.status_date = data[trial].get('current_trial_status_date')
        ct.start_date = data[trial].get('start_date')
        ct.start_date_type_code = data[trial].get('start_date_type_code')
        ct.completion_date = data[trial].get('completion_date')
        ct.record_verification_date = data[trial].get('record_verification_date')
        ct.completion_date_type_code = data[trial].get('completion_date_type_code')
        ct.brief_title = data[trial].get('brief_title')
        ct.official_title = data[trial].get('official_title')
        ct.brief_title = data[trial].get('brief_title')
        ct.brief_summary = data[trial].get('brief_summary')
        ct.primary_purpose_code = data[trial].get('primary_purpose').get('primary_purpose_code')
        ct.phase = data[trial].get('phase').get('phase')
        ct.minimum_target_accrual_number = data[trial].get('minimum_target_accrual_number')
        ct.number_of_arms = data[trial].get('number_of_arms')
        ct.lead_org_name = data[trial].get('lead_org')
        try:
            ct.lead_org_fk = Company.objects.get(company_name__startswith=data[trial].get('lead_org'))
        except:
            pass

        ct.save()
        pk = ct.pk  # added this to try and get the below to work

        # add collaborators
        if collaborators is not None:
            for x in range(len(collaborators)):
                try:
                    # add m2m key to ClinicalTrial model
                    key = Company.objects.get(company_name__startswith=collaborators[x])
                    ct.collaborators = ct.collaborators.add(key)
                    print('ct.collab added')
                    ct.save()

                    # not all companies will be linked above due to syntax, this adds the text name to a separate table
                    c, _ = Collaborator.objects.get_or_create(company=collaborators[x])
                    c.save()
                    ct = ClinicalTrial.objects.get(pk=pk)
                    c.clinical_trials = c.clinical_trials.add(ct)
                    c.save()
                except:
                    pass

        # add diseases
        if data[trial].get('diseases') is not None:
            len_diseases = len(data[trial].get('diseases'))
            for x in range(len_diseases):
                d, _ = Disease.objects.get_or_create(
                    disease_code=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('disease_code'),
                    preferred_name=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('preferred_name'),
                    display_name=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('display_name'))
                d.save()
                ct = ClinicalTrial.objects.get(pk=pk)
                d.clinical_trials = d.clinical_trials.add(ct)
                d.save()

    return
```

**Here's what my models.py looks like:**

```
from django.db import models
from dashboard.models import Company


class ClinicalTrial(models.Model):
    # companies involved
    lead_org_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lead_org_fk = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='ct_lead_org', null=True)
    collaborators_m2m = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    # model details
    nct_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    status_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    start_date_type_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    completion_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    completion_date_type_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='', null=True)
    record_verification_date = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    brief_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    official_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    brief_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    study_protocol_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    primary_purpose_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    minimum_target_accrual_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    number_of_arms = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.official_title


class Disease(models.Model):
    clinical_trials = models.ManyToManyField(ClinicalTrial, related_name='disease')
    disease_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)


class Collaborator(models.Model):
    clinical_trials = models.ManyToManyField(ClinicalTrial, related_name='collaborator')
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I couldn't seem to find any code examples online of how to actually post values to a ManyToManyField.  Anyways, here's how I was able to get this to work for others that are facing a similar issue.

Escentially there were two things I learned.  First, this is how to add an item to ManyToManyField `d.clinical_trials.add(ct.pk)`.  Second, if you are using the get_or_create() command you don't need to save the model before adding a ManyToManyField value.

Here's a code snippet of the function in the OP versus what I changed.

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------    
# ORIGINAL CODE FROM OP
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# add m2m key to ClinicalTrial model
key = Company.objects.get(company_name__startswith=collaborators[x])
ct.collaborators = ct.collaborators.add(key)
print('ct.collab added')
ct.save()

# not all companies will be linked above due to syntax, this adds the text name to a separate table
c, _ = Collaborator.objects.get_or_create(company=collaborators[x])
c.save()
ct = ClinicalTrial.objects.get(pk=pk)
c.clinical_trials = c.clinical_trials.add(ct)
c.save()

# add diseases
if data[trial].get('diseases') is not None:
    len_diseases = len(data[trial].get('diseases'))
    for x in range(len_diseases):
        d, _ = Disease.objects.get_or_create(
            disease_code=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('disease_code'),
            preferred_name=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('preferred_name'),
            display_name=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('display_name'))
        d.save()
        ct = ClinicalTrial.objects.get(pk=pk)
        d.clinical_trials = d.clinical_trials.add(ct)
        d.save()

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# NEW CODE
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# add m2m key to ClinicalTrial model
key = Company.objects.get(company_name__startswith=collaborators[x])
ct.collaborators = ct.collaborators.add(key.PK)

# not all companies will be linked above due to syntax, this adds the text name to a separate table
c, _ = Collaborator.objects.get_or_create(company=collaborators[x])
c.clinical_trials.add(ct.pk)
c.save()

# add diseases
if data[trial].get('diseases') is not None:
    len_diseases = len(data[trial].get('diseases'))
    for x in range(len_diseases):
        d, _ = Disease.objects.get_or_create(
            disease_code=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('disease_code'),
            preferred_name=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('preferred_name'),
            display_name=data[trial].get('diseases')[x].get('display_name'))
        d.clinical_trials.add(ct.pk)
        d.save()
```